# How to sort explicitly positive and negative numbers with GNU sort?

Tags: shell, sorting, gnu-sort

Given a file containing the following numbers:

```
+1.4
+12.3
-1.0
-4.2
```

How would one sort it with GNU sort in numerical order?

Using `-n` or `-h` doesn't seem to work: the `+` character is not being treated correctly?

```
$ echo "+1.4\n+12.3\n-4.2\n-1.0" | sort -h
-4.2
-1.0
+12.3
+1.4
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash  :

```
echo -e "+1.4\n+12.3\n-4.2\n-1.0" | sort -g
```

should do the trick. `-e` with `echo` interprets escape sequences. `-g` with `sort` compares according to general numerical value.

**Sample Output**

```
$ echo -e "+1.4\n+12.3\n-4.2\n-1.0" | sort -g
-4.2
-1.0
+1.4
+12.3
```

<sup>**Sidenote:** In some shells, `echo -e` is the default behavior. Check [[ this  ]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) ...</sup>

Answer (score 0):

One option is stripping the `+` characters, sorting, then adding them again.

```
$ echo "+1.4\n+12.3\n-1.0\n-4.2" \
    | sed 's/^\+//' \
    | sort -h \n
    | sed -E 's/^([^-])/\+\1/
-4.2
-1.0
+1.4
+12.3
```

Comment: If there's a way to do this without resorting to text manipulation, I'd accept that answer.